# Sign of the Hankel representation of the Gamma function

Tags: special-functions, contour-integration

[image]

I have a question about the Hankel path representation of the Gamma function.
The path of integration is displayed on the imege.
The branch cut is taken as the negative real axis.
$$
 \Gamma(z) = \frac{1}{2 i \sin { \pi z}} \int_{Ha} e^t t^{z-1} dt
$$

In my derivation I actually get
$$
 \Gamma(z) = \frac{-1}{2 i \sin { \pi z}} \int_{Ha} e^t t^{z-1} dt
$$
by the substitution along AB:  $t= x e^{i\pi}$ and along ED: $ x e^{- i\pi}$.
Let $z>0$ so that the arch integral would vanish.

The sum of the ray integrals eventually becomes
$$
I = - e^{i \pi z} \int_{\epsilon}^{\infty} e^{-x} x^{z-1} dx +  e^{-i \pi z} \int_{\epsilon}^{\infty} e^{-x} x^{z-1} dx
$$
which for $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ becomes
$$
I = - 2i\sin{\pi z} \; \Gamma(z)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the ray $DE$. The integral is
$$\int_{-\infty}^0 (t - i \epsilon)^{z - 1} e^{t - i \epsilon} dt =
\int_{-\infty}^0
 e^{(z - 1)(\ln |t - i \epsilon| + i \arg(t - i \epsilon))}
 e^{t - i \epsilon} dt \to \\
e^{-i \pi (z - 1)} \int_{-\infty}^0 (-t)^{z - 1} e^t dt =
-e^{-i \pi z} \int_0^\infty t^{z - 1} e^{-t} dt,$$
so the signs in $I$ are off.

Comment: How do you get the 3rd step?

Comment: Do you mean the limit? Interchanging the integral and the limit, we get $e^{(z - 1) \ln |t - i \epsilon|} \to e^{(z - 1) \ln |t|} = |t|^{z - 1}$ and $\arg(t - i \epsilon) \to -\pi$ when $\epsilon \to 0^+$.